# JSF Primefaces download file

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am currently working on JSF PrimeFaces, I want to download file which is present in my project name  "CV " folder but facing issues here is the code below

File upload:

```html
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload
        fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUploadCv}"
        mode="advanced" update="messages"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx)$/" />
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
</h:form>
```

File download:

```html
<h:form id="form11">
    <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download Cv" ajax="false"
        onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"
        icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Here is the controller class:

```
import java.io.InputStream;  
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;  
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;  
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileDownloadController {  

    private StreamedContent file;  

    public FileDownloadController() {

        InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("D:/Final Year Project/displayjob-portlet/docroot/cv/Junaid.cv");  
        System.out.print("inside download111");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream);  
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: you're "facing issues". tell us, what those are.

Comment: coud'nt be able to download file.no response

Comment: please check the server logs and the error console in your browser and then say what youve got there. 2nd one isn't of any interest yet if you find errors in the logs.

Comment: No error found in console of browser or server

Comment: @Zhedar No error found in console of browser or server when i click download button it just refresh and does nothing

Comment: you say, you want to download a file... why do you use a file**uploader** then?

Comment: @Zhedar   <h:form id="form11">
    <br/><br/>
     <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download Cv" ajax="false"
      onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)"
      icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s">
      <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" />
     </p:commandButton>

    </h:form>

Comment: @JunaidAkhtar you can edit your question/answer in order to provide more info.

Comment: @Zhedar Sorry i posted wrong code.  <h:form id="form11"> <br/><br/> <p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download Cv" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)" icon="ui-icon-arrowthichk-s"> <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" /> </p:commandButton> </h:form>

Comment: I can't see any difference between your last comment and the comment before it.

Comment: By the way, when creating the `FileDownloadController` managed bean, have you debugged if the `stream` variable has a real value and not a `null`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a file from your pc and not from the server. Since the application is running on a server, the root directory is your server domain root directory.
Try to put the file inside the server and change the directory of it.
For example you can create a folder inside the root directory of server called filesToDownload and put your file inside it. Then you should find it like this:

```
InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("filesToDownload/Junaid.cv");
```

I know that this issue is a bit old, but as I was facing same problem, I think this answer might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add that script in your page ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    PF('statusDialog').show();
}

function stop() {
    PF('statusDialog').hide();
}
</script>
```